# Assisgning data from txt file with multiple columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

Hi I have a txt file that has two columns (with space in between) for example:

```
IP1 MAC1
IP2 MAC2
IP3 MAC3
```

and so on (these will be actual IP addresses and MAC addresses)

I need help with a loop that knows IP1 and MAC1 are in one line and are related.

I am trying to write a program that uses the loop and uses first column text (ip address) and logs into the switch and uses 2nd column value (MAC address) to assign MAC in port security. It then goes to next line and gets second IP and MAC and does same thing and so on until end of file.

I have login and commands setup but I am having issues getting data from text and looping so IP1 knows it needs has MAC1.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: can you not use pandas dataframe ? Load the file and loop through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get you started, I have an example. Putting the ip and macs separated by a space in a file called "file.txt", you can run this code:

```
with open('file.txt') as input_file:
    for i, line in enumerate(input_file):
        line = line.strip()
        ip, mac = line.split()
        print("ip: " + ip + ", mac: " + mac)
```

which will output the following:

```
ip: IP1, mac: MAC1
ip: IP2, mac: MAC2
ip: IP3, mac: MAC3
```

I agree with Scott Hunter however that it seems that you've made no attempt to solve this problem yourself, which is surprising because your technical lingo with IPs and MACs is evidence that you could google and find your answers (that's what I did).

Comment: By the way, I did this in python because of the tags you attached; you really do need to provide *some* code when posting on Stack Overflow

Comment: Damn! you FGITW'd me

Comment: Ha I've never heard of that -- with the obligatory google search I now understand. Haha, sorry to beat you to it!

Comment: I did have a code for logging into the switch and executing command but posting that here would not have helped as it is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Open the file and make a list of tuples [(ip1, mac1), (ip2, mac2)..]

txt_file = open("text.txt", "r")
x = [x.rstrip().split() for x in file.readlines()]

#now make a dictionary where key = ip, v = MAC
dict_ = {k: v for k, v in x}

# You now have a dictionary where you can get the MAC from ip via
>>>dict_['ip address'] 
>>>MAC
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will give you alternate way of doing this:

```
import pandas as pd
filename =r'c:\temp\input.txt'
list =  pd.read_csv(filename, sep=' ', skiprows=0, header=None).fillna('')
for i, row in list.iterrows():
    print '-'.join(p for p in row)

Output
IP1-MAC1
IP2-MAC2
IP3-MAC3
```